# Feats to increase the number of spells per day for a wizard

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, character-creation

Looking for feats or feat combos to increase the number of wizard spells my character can cast per day.

This wizard focuses on conjuration and necromancy, level 7 with a 24 int score. Other feats include tomb tainted soul, spell focus necromancy, fearsome necromancy, stitched familiar, spellcasting prodigy and craft wonderous item.

School specialist necromancy prohibited abjuration and enchantment.

Deep imaskari race

All books and dragon magazines fair game.

Lawful evil alignment.

Comment: Is there a reason you particularly want feats, and not, say, the Guild Mage prestige class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So far as I can tell, that necromancer only has a few options:

- The Abyssal heritor feat **Chaotic Spell Recall** (*Fiendish Codex I* 84) allows the creature 1/day +1/day per 2 Abyssal heritor feats the creature possesses to recall—as if it hadn't been cast—a spell with the descriptor chaotic. *Note:* "A character with… one Abyssal heritor feat can be of any alignment, but he immediately becomes chaotic (if he wasn’t already) upon
  taking a second, unless he possesses the Ordered Chaos feat" (82), and alignment gravitates more toward chaotic evil the more heritor feats possessed.
- The metamagic feat **Echoing Spell** (*Secrets of Xen'drik* 134-5) allows a creature to prepare a spell at 3 levels higher. After casting a spell so prepared, 1 hour later the caster regains the ability to cast that spell… as if the creature were a caster 4 levels lower than the previous casting. This effect continues until the caster's effective caster level for casting that spell is lower than the minimum needed to cast the spell. (Thus an echoing spell can only be cast twice total unless also heightened *via* the feat [Heighten Spell](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#heighten-spell) (*PH* 95).)
- The general feat **Extra Slot** (*Complete Arcane* 79) grants the caster 1 additional spell slot of up to 1 level lower than the creature's highest spell slot, picked when the feat's gained. (For example, a level 9 wizard that can typically cast 5th-level spells can take the feat Extra Slot to gain an addition 4th-level or lower spell slot.) This feat can be taken multiple times.
- The general feat **Far Look** (*Dragon* #330 27) grants the caster 1 additional slot of up to the highest spell level the caster can cast that can be filled *only* with a cerebrosis spell unique to the article. (For example, a level 9 wizard that can typically cast 5th-level spells that gains once the feat Far Look can use the slot to prepare 1 0-, 1st-, 2nd-, 3rd-, 4th-, or 5th-level cerebrosis spell.) This feat is gained *via* a ritual (and, apparently, *can't* be taken upon gaining a level) and can be gained multiple times, but it reduces the creature's Wisdom score by 2 each time it's gained. *Note:* This might be worth looking into depending on that necromancer's Wisdom score; several of the cerebrosis spells are pretty good conjuration (summoning) spells.
- The general feat **Node Store** (*Champions of Ruin* 26) allows the caster to pick 2 spells he could prepare and cast them while in his attuned node. Chances are, unless the DM's skewed the campaign toward this *really* niche idea, your PC isn't mucking about with the complicated, intricate rules for nodes.

Other options may exist; this is challenging topic to research. And, obviously, the game makes what's asked *very* difficult—casting more spells is generally what leveling up is for! (Instead of feats, I recommend a magic item like a [*ring of wizardry*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsPRR.html#ring-of-wizardry) (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 233) (20,000+ gp; 0 lbs.).)